# Is using a default member initializer with a previously default member-initialized variable legal?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++17, member-initialization

The following code unsurprisingly fails when used:

```
struct Foo {
  std::string b = a + " world"; // a not declared yet
  std::string a = "Hello";
};
```

because we're attempting to use `a` before having defined it and due to [[class.base.init]/13.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.init#class.base.init-13.3):

> Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).

But what about this code?

```
struct Foo {
  std::string a = "Hello";
  std::string b = a + " world";
};
```

13.3 seems reasonable here as well (making the code *well-defined*), however I am not sure that it covers the situation in the listing above, because it mentions mem-initializers but misses this specific case (IMO). I admit this may simply be a lack of English skills, so I prefer to ask.

Does the referenced paragraph in the standard make the code

1. Well-defined (my guess)
2. Undefined behavior
3. Or is it the wrong paragraph? If so, please point me to the correct location.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Looking from that perspective, I agree. Just wondering now if I should vote for a dupe of my own post or simply delete the question (don't want to ask Meta SO for that...)

Comment: It would be a useful signpost IMHO.  If you want I can dupe hammer it.

Comment: Replacing comment that got auto removed: If you consider that in class initialization is just syntactic sugar for a member initialization list then the dupe answers if it is allowed.

Comment: Now it's too late I guess :-) I would have answered my own question and explained the slight difference to the referenced one, but I think that most people will get the point when they read the other answer.